# Delete unanswered question, even though valid, but no longer a blocker

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

**Background**

A few months ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182741/angular4-angular-flex-layout-not-working-in-child-modules-with-secondary-router) that since has gone unanswered. Not being able to find a solution to the problem myself I eventually changed the architecture of my application to bypass the issue. However, it seems at least one other person has had the same issue and the question has some upvotes.

**Standard S.O. practice seems to dictate not deleting unanswered questions, in favor of editing/updating it to bring it back to life in the new questions queue and renew interest.**

However, as mentioned this question is no longer an issue for me, and I have been unable to reproduce the issue in a simplified StackBlitz. I'm concerned it may have been scoped to a versioning problem, but I don't recall what all the package versions I was using at the time, because I have upgraded multiple times since.

**Question:** Do I delete the question, even though it may still be valid, but not to me?

Comment: Turn it to a community wiki... oh wait, you can't... nevermind.

Answer (score 24):

The question, as it stands, doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem.  That alone is grounds for its closure.  The purpose of said closure would be to provide an opportunity for you to improve the question such that it would contain enough information for a reproducible example.  It seems that you're both unable to do that (as you can no longer reproduce the problem yourself) and also don't really have a reason to do it (as you've avoided the problem entirely, so you simply aren't seeking a solution any more).  Given that, it would seem that the question doesn't have a particularly realistic shot at turning into an answerable question.  Since the question isn't answerable, and probably won't become answerable, it's probably best to just delete it.

If someone else ends up having the same problem, they can post their own question in which they are hopefully able to provide enough information to reproduce the problem, so that it can be answered.

If the question contained a clear and reproducible problem, and as a result was an answerable question, and you just no longer needed the solution to that problem anymore, then by all means, keep the question around, even if it isn't answered, in case someone decides to post an answer for anyone else who might have that problem.  It simply isn't productive *here* because the question doesn't have enough information to reproduce the problem, and so isn't really answerable as is.

Comment: This is the solution I was leaning towards, as I don't want to pollute the site with unanswerable questions.  I will proceed with deleting the question. Thank you for your response, @Servy.

Answer (score -12):

Leave it for now.

If the question is clearly no longer reproducible, then people will vote to close it as such. (You have enough rep that you can do so yourself, if you wish. Your vote for closure will not be binding.)

Once it's closed, it will eventually get deleted on its own.

However, that you cannot reproduce it doesn't mean others cannot. And someone may one day come along with the answer. The question doesn't hurt the site by staying open.

Comment: Why on earth would you rely on the ability of other people to reproduce the problem instead of the question author's ability to reproduce the problem?

Comment: As I said, the author can vote to close it as well. If you disagree with my answer, you can always post your own.

Comment: Or we can express our disagreement by downvoting :-)

Comment: Depends on a question, but some times the fact that other people had a problem can be valuable information, as can be the fact that they can no longer reproduce it ( it says to me that it might be possible to solve a problem by upgrading...)